# I have a problem with the encoding of the characterset in a pdf

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I have a customer who is receiving orders in a pdf. Of course there is an amount mentioned. I use ghostscript to make a picture of it.
The funny thing is that the euro sign is translated to a chinese (?) symbol.
On my own testserver it is going well, maar but not on his server.
Any ideas how to tackle this problem?
See this link: http://www.ksa-automatisering.nl/documents/euro.png.
Maarten

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer. It's probably a font thing, but you already knew that. PDF's can embed fonts they use, or not. If they do, the font should display correctly, but if they don't the font gets substituted. And there lies the problem. Do the font, originally used in the PDF, and the substituted font match up correctly? Since the Euro sign is a somewhat later addition (> 1999) to the character sets of fonts, there will still be fonts out there that don't support it. The trick is to find out which is the substituted font, and then update that to include the euro sign.

Comment: Alternatively you could check which font the PDF wants to use and install it on the server that uses Ghostscript. Basically this is a problem originating with the sender of the PDF. They should embed the font.

Comment: I have searched for a way to find out the character set used. But found no solution.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-fonts.html